# Why is this showing "Invalid type conversion"?

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, msp430

I have this piece of C code (For MSP430 platforms, `cl430` compiler):

```
void function(uint8_t * x){
    // This variable is defined in the linker file as "X_ADDR = 0xE000;"
    extern uint32_t X_ADDR; 
    uint16_t i = 0;
    uint16_t size = 10;
    uint32_t dst_addr = (uint32_t) &X_ADDR; 

    for (i=0; i < size; i++){
         *((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x+i); // <-- This line shows the warning
}
```

What I understand is this, but here is where I guess I am wrong:

```
*((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x + i);
                |       |       |   |
                V       V       V   V
*((uint8_t *) (u32  + u16)) = *(u8*+u16);
       *((uint8_t *) (u32)) = *(u8*);
                     *(u8*) = u8;
                         u8 = u8;
```

This platform is 16-bits but it supports an extended addressing mode of 20-bits.

Any hint on this? and how should it be done instead? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the full error message.

Comment: Actually the full message is `#173-D invalid type conversion`

Comment: It usually points the types for which the conversion is invalid.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using `cl430`, TI's compiler for MSP430 platforms

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Hah ok so in your case it isn't complaining about going from 32 bit to 64 bit, but from 32 bit to 16 bit. Right? I'm pretty sure MSP430 got 16 bit addresses. If so, then this code is fishy for different reasons.

Comment: Yes, it is 16bit. I will update the question with detailed info.

Comment: @Lundin You say fishy, I say suspect :-)

Comment: Actually, somewhere in the back of my mind I have some story about TI and 20 bit addresses... wasn't it MSP430 that have very strange addresses in some versions?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Not fishy because it is an integer to pointer conversion, but fishy because the integer used won't even fit in the address bus of the intended target.

Comment: So `FFABCD` would be a case for `*far` pointers or something evil like that. That's commonly how it's done on other 16 bitters with evil addressing modes beyond 16 bit. `uintptr_t` is the correct solution still, for 16 bit addresses.

Comment: There is an extended 20-bit address option for devices with more than 64K of memory, but that option is not used for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to get this on 64 bit compilers that use 64 bit pointers. Converting a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit pointer is questionable and non-portable.

Correct this by using the portable integer type meant to be used for this very purpose:

```
uintptr_t dst_addr = 0x00FFABCD;
```

Now it will compile cleanly on all mainstream 64 bit compilers. Tried on gcc, clang icc with `-std=c11 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic-errors`, no problems.

In addition, when accessing an absolute address, you will almost certainly need to `volatile` qualify the pointer.

Comment: Is there good reason *not* to declare `dst_addr` as `uint8_t *dst_addr = (uint8_t *) 0x00FFABCD;`?  This is well outside of my wheelhouse, so I simply don't know why you wouldn't use a pointer type to begin with.

Comment: @JohnBode There's one good reason: the OP is doing arithmetic and it's always better to do arithmetic on integer types than pointer types. If you convert to `uint8_t*` first, then add some offset with pointer arithmetic, you aren't pointing within the bounds of an allocated array and technically you invoke UB at that point. Better to calculate the absolute address on integer types, then convert to pointers afterwards.

Comment: As you pointed out, the warning was due to a mismatch in the pointer size. The code is for that large memory model with 20-bit addresses, but it wasn't used. So changing `uint32_t dst_addr = (uint32_t) &X_ADDR;` to `uint16_t` or `uintptr_t` clears the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's objecting to the conversion of the integer `dst_addr` to a pointer, not the assignment of the `uint8_t`

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -W type.c
type.c: In function 'function':
type.c:11:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
          *((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x+i); // <-- This line shows the warning
            ^
```

and clang offers similar:

```
$ clang -c type.c -W -Wall
type.c:11:12: warning: cast to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from smaller integer type 'unsigned int'
      [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         *((uint8_t *) (dst_addr+i)) = *(x+i); // <-- This line shows the warning
           ^
```

(clang 3.4.2; gcc 4.8.5)

Converting from an int to a pointer is always suspect, and I'm not sure there's a way to tell the compiler that you really meant it, at least if you turn on all the warnings (which is a good practice).

Comment: "Converting from an int to a pointer is always suspect" No it is perfectly fine and common practice when doing any form of hardware related programming.

Comment: Being fine and being suspect are not mutually exclusive; it's of course very common when doing embedded work - I've  done this myself - but it's exactly an area where it's easy to get stuff wrong, and *most* of the time when it gives this warning, the compiler is waving you off a mistake.  This may not be one of those cases.

Comment: This isn't even the reason why the compiler warns though... I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a 32-bit integer into a 16-bit pointer.

To ensure that your integer type has the same size as a pointer, use `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

---

And when you treating `X_ADDR` as a byte array, it would be a better idea to declare it as such:

```
extern uint8_t X_ADDR[];

X_ADDR[i] = ...;
```